# How to save a model instance using custom APIView in Django REST API?

Tags: django, rest, authentication, django-rest-framework

I am developing a website which is build on 2 servers: Django(back), ReactJS(front); (I have changed some titles to abstract names for the sake of convenience)

Model:

```
class Model(model.Model):
    attr1 = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    attr1 = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    ....
    **author = models.ForeignKey(UserModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)**
```

Custom Create View:

```
class ModelCreateAPI(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        serializer = serializers.ModelSerializer(data=request.data)   
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            model_saved = serializer.save()
        return Response({"success": "Model created successfully"})
```

Serializer:

```
class ModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Model
        fields = '__all__'
```

On my React APP there is a form that sends HTTP request, including 'user token', that is stored in localStorage. However, 'author' of model should be an integer that represents pk. I have managed to convert token to pk:

```
>>> from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
>>> Token.objects.get(key='token').user_id
```

Is it an effective way of doing this operation?
What are your suggestions?
How I can implement HTTP POST request in way that it saves the model with correct author_id?

Comment: Using Token Approach is best., if you are using `JSON web token`., it will be more secure.

Comment: If someone knows the form of the request that creates/deletes/updates an instance, and have any user's token, then it is not secure at all. Is there any other more secure way?

Comment: That's a disadvantage of using native tokens.. Using jwt is more safer as you can provide a shorter term of them being usable..